# Integer doesn't increase when working with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The int i doesn't seem to be increasing, and while or for loops don't seem to work in the array. What is the reason for this? The row changes whenever I click, and I'm trying to get the row # in an arraylist.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> XCordPasted(int Row, int Column){

    ArrayList<Integer> XCord = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int row = Row * (int)NumWidthTextures;
    int statRow = row;
    int i = 0;
    int g = i;

    if(XCord.isEmpty()){
        XCord.add(i,statRow);
        i=1;
    }else{
        XCord.add(i,statRow);
        i++;
    }
    if(XCord.size()>1){
        if(XCord.get(g-1)==XCord.get(g)){
            XCord.remove(g);
            i=XCord.size();
        }
    }
    return XCord;
}
```

Comment: What are you try to do? What is your algorithm supposed to do?

Comment: This seems like a great time to learn how to [debug](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)!

Comment: I don't see any loops. Also i is set to 0 each time XCordPasted is called so i only will ever become 1 based on your if else statements and lack of loops in the method.

Comment: Also, how big are the numbers? `if(XCord.get(g-1)==XCord.get(g)){` might be biting you.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few thoughts on your code (without knowing its purpose):

`public static ArrayList<Integer> XCordPasted(int Row, int Column){`

Row and Column shouldn't be capitalized.

`int statRow = row;`

What's the point of creating a new variable `statrow` that is the same as `row`? Also, why use the name `row` when that's already the name of one of the parameters of the method?

```
if(XCord.isEmpty()){
    XCord.add(i,statRow);
        i=1;
} else{
    XCord.add(i,statRow);
    i++;
}
```

At this point in the code, XCord must be empty. There is no reason to have `if` and `else` statements. Perhaps you meant to have a loop here?

```
if(XCord.size()>1){
    if(XCord.get(g-1)==XCord.get(g)){
        XCord.remove(g);
        i=XCord.size();
    }
}
```

At this point in the code, XCord must have a size of 1. The condition inside the `if` statement must be false, so it doesn't do what's inside the block of code.

Therefore, the return simply returns an `XCord` with one element: `statrow`.

Please update your question to say what the method is meant to do. I notice one of the parameters isn't even used (`int Column` - which also should be lowercase, incidentally).

Comment: Yes the question doesn't follow Java conventions, we do highly recommend them, but we don't REQUIRE naming conventions. It's just the icing on the cake.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose a lower case name isn't required. It was just annoying me how the code shows up the color of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe posting more details of the program would help clarify the overall logic. :-)

Until then, based on the posted code, every time the `XCordPasted()` method is called, the `XCord` value is initialized to a new `ArrayList`, so the conditional statement

```
if (XCord.isEmpty())
{
    ...
}
```

is always `true`, thus the returned `ArrayList` always has exactly 1 member and the `int i` parameter will always be set to `1`.

Also, the `int g` parameter is only set once to `i` (= 0), so it will always have a value of `0`. If the condition `(XCord.size()>1)` were ever to be true, there would have been an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because of the `XCord.get(g-1)` call.